# Jquery 200parsererror

Tags: jquery

I have an jquery ajax request with datatype string when executed, i get correct value from server side but in jquery it gives 200parsererror.The function is for export to excel and it was working fine with jquery 1.4.4 but with jquery 1.6.1 it is giving error.

the jquery  code is:-

```
 $.ajax({ type: "POST", //method post
        url: URL, //use weservice method          
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "string",
        data:"{}",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            AjaxSucceeded(data); //if success call sucess function
        },
        error: AjaxFailed//if failed call fail function
    });
```

After entering success it goes in AjaxFailed ().
From server side I m passing this

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"><meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet><meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 9"><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name></x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:Selected/><x:ProtectContents>False</x:ProtectContents><x:ProtectObjects>False</x:ProtectObjects><x:ProtectScenarios>False</x:ProtectScenarios></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ProtectStructure>False</x:ProtectStructure><x:ProtectWindows>False</x:ProtectWindows></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><style>

                        @page

                        {

                        mso-header-data:'&R Date: &D Time: &T';

                        mso-footer-data:'&L Proprietary & Confidential &R Page &P of &N';

                        }

                        </style></head><body><table><tr><td>Company/Projects</td><td>2001 Jan</td><td>2001 Feb</td><td>2002 Jan</td><td>Total Revenue</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

Please let me know how to get over it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"string" is not a valid dataType, you probably want dataType: "text".

Enjoy your Ajax